# I keep getting a jshint error in atom (E030 - Expected an identifier and instead saw '1'. ) when i try to render an h1 element with react

Tags: reactjs

I am new to reactjs and I enabled jshint. I wrote my first react code but I keep getting the following jshint error in line --> ReactDom.render.....:

**E030 - Expected an identifier and instead saw '1'.**

```
/*jshint esversion: 6 */

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello World</h1>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <title>React App</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script type="text/babel" src="../src/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use ESLint instead.

Comment: Consider using ESLint instead, it's much more flexible with modern JavaScript (including JSX) than JSHint